# Is that true that $ H \trianglelefteq G $, then $ G/H \trianglelefteq G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$ G/H = \{xH \mid x \in G\} $ , so if $ y \in G $, then
$$ 
y(G/H)y^{-1} = \{yxHy^{-1} \mid x \in G \}  = \{ yxy^{-1}H \mid x \in G \} 
$$
(Because $H$ is normal, so $ y^{-1}H = H y^{-1} $)

so $ y(G/H)y^{-1} \subseteq G/H $ for all $ y \in G $

so $ G/H \trianglelefteq G $

Is there something mistake?

Comment: G/H is not necessarily a subgroup

Comment: Oh thx. I had a big mistake..

Comment: $G/H$ is technically not even a subset of $G$. If $H\trianglelefteq G$ has a *complement* $K$ (that is, a subgroup $K\le G$ for which $G=HK$ and $H\cap K$ - note this isn't the same as being a direct product, only a semidirect product), then $G/H\cong K$ are isomorphic. In general, $G/H$ may not be isomorphic to a subgroup $K\le G$. Even if it is isomorphic to a subgroup $K$, it may not be isomorphic to any complementary subgroup, in which case $G/H\cong K$ is in some sense "unnatural" or "coincidental."

Comment: What *is* true is that you can let $G$ **act** on $G/H$ via conjugation (or equivalently, that the action of $G$ by conjugation factors through $G/H$, since $H$ is closed under the action). That is what you are observing.

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't really make sense. If $H\subseteq G$ is a subgroup, then $G/H$ is not by definition a subset of $G$. If $H$ is normal, then $G/H$ is a group, but there may not even exist a nontrivial group homomorphism $G/H\to G$. Indeed, take $G=\Bbb{Z}$ and $H=n\Bbb{Z}$. Then $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ has no nontrivial map to $\Bbb{Z}$. Indeed, if $[k]\mapsto a$, the $n\cdot a=0$, and hence $a=0$.